# Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: php, laravel, status

While trying to change the status of user i am facing this problem.
in route:

```
 Route::get('userstatus/{id}/{status}', 'UserController@changeStatus');
```

in controller:

```
public function changeStatus($id, $status, User $user)
    {

        $user->update(array('status' => $status), $id);

        return redirect('users');


    }
```

In database i am storing status like :
"active"
"banned"
"hold"
why am i getting this problem?is there any solution?

Comment: the second parameter should be an array.. i mean the $id should be an array..but $id is always an int/string

Comment: $user->update(array('status' => $status,'id' => $id));   if i write above code it doesnt shows error but database is not updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use it like below:

```
$user->where('id', $id)->update(array('status' => $status));
```

See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#basic-updates)

Comment: how to close this question now